# Processing RXTX issue

Tags: arduino, serial, linux, processing, port

I am new to **Processing** and attempting to write code to communicate with my **Arduino** - on a **linux** platform.

When I run the following code:

```
println(Serial.list());
```

I'm supposed to get a list of available ports through which communication with Arduinos/computer is/are possible but instead I get the following message:

```
WARNING: RXTX Version mismatch
Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
```

**I don't know anything about Processing nor why this message is coming up ... I really need help.**

Comment: System is running on java version "1.6.0_24"

Comment: What does this have to do with electrical engineering?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://seeingthefoss.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/using-processings-rxtx-with-arduino-on-linux/) helpful link which leverages the Arduino's RXTX solution to resolve the same issue for processing.

Having followed the instructions, my warning message is gone and I now get available port information delivered to my application.

Comment: please rewrite the solution here, rather than linking to it. I should have done the same thing. Reason being that the page might change or dissappear. From what I can tell, the thing with the stack exchange sites is to put the answer on the site so people dont have to go elsewhere.